# Why are there many notations for expected value?

Tags: statistics, notation

I saw from literature that the expected value of a random variable $f(X)$ is either $E f(X)$, $E(f(X))$ or $E[f(X)]$. Is there a standard which one notation should one use? Is the expected value a function $f(X)\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: I think the standard is usually $\text{E}\left [ f(X) \right ]$ from what I've seen in stats texts.

Comment: Interesting, observant question. There seems to be no standard, and sometimes this causes confusion, especially for beginning students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally up to the author. Some authors use a different
typeface for the $E$ and they tend to be the ones who avoid
parentheses or brackets: $\mathbf{E}X,$ $\mathbb{E}X,$ $\mathsf{E}X$, and so on (including a script E, which I've forgotten how to make).

It is also common to use $\mu$ when there is only one random
variable under discussion or $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ when there are
several. This make is convenient to write expressions such as
$E(X - \mu_X)^2$ without accumulating too many brackets or parentheses.
as in $E\{[X - E(X)]^2\}.$

As for your second question: A random variable is a function
from the sample space to the real numbers, sometimes written as
$\Omega \stackrel{X}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}.$ Moreover, if $f$ is a function
from the real numbers to the real numbers then $f(X)$ is another
random variable. Then we might write $\Omega \stackrel{X}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R} \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}$ or
$\Omega \stackrel{f(X)}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}.$ Expectation itself is not a function (because it yields a constant);
the word 'operator' is often used for the process of producing
that constant.

I see that another Answer by @Karl has appeared with some entirely
different notations for expected values. Outside the mainstream
of mathematical statistics, there are many more such notations.

One potentially confusing notation for math stat people is common in queueing
theory where $L$ can stand for the AVERAGE number of people
in a queueing system, $L_Q$ for the average number of
people waiting to be served, $W_Q$ for the average time
waiting to be served, and so on. The random variables themselves
are seldom mentioned and have a variety of notations other than
capital letters when they are mentioned.

Adding to the diversity is the routine use of small Greek letters (such
as $\xi$ and $\eta$) or small Roman letters (such as $\text{a}$ amd $\text{b}$ for random variables, common in some European and Asian
countries.

Comment: great answer. (+1)  I didn't answer the maps to part because I thought that the expectation could map into the set of polynomials in $t$ and didn't quite know how to say it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen $\langle X \rangle$ used as well for expected value. I quite like this as it makes moment generating functions look nice $\langle e^{tX}  \rangle$ only has one 'e' compared with $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]$
I guess that's your answer, people choose notation to balance form and function. I suspect there is no standard notation just some are more common than others.

Comment: Nice comment on MGFs.(+1) to you too.

Comment: I've also seen this notation used by some physicists. But, of course, this is very misleading, because $\langle X \rangle$ denotes the compensator (https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/compensators/) of a stochastic process $X$ in the Doob-Meyer decomposition (https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/the-doob-meyer-decomposition/).